# D&D Dice Rerolling; Likelihood of specific outcomes given

Tags: probability, combinatorics, dice

**Background**
In Dungeons and Dragons we (typically) roll $20$ sided dice. In my hypothetical situation on my roll I add a +11 to the outcome and if it's not at least a $20$ then I get to reroll the $20$ sided dice once again.

The question follows: What is the probability of me getting at least a $20$ on my turn (the original role, and the secondary roll if needed).

**My logic**
We are basically looking for $> 8$ on the roll since a  $9$ would meet the criteria with the $+11$ bonus. A normal D20 would have an average of a $10.5$ on any particular role. On the first role I have a $12/20$ chance. I'm not exactly sure why but I feel like I can substuite any number lower than the needed $8$ with the average on the dice of a 10.5 So it would be:

$(8*10.5)$ + ${\sum_{i=9}^{20} i}$ = 258

so the odds of a success *should* be:
$1 -\frac{20}{258}$ or 92.2%

If this is correct, why? It feels correct but I can't prove to myself why it would be.

**Edit**
I fixed some silly grammatical and calculation errors.

Comment: The average value of a roll on a D20 (with labels 1-20) is not a 10, it's actually 10.5 -- you can get this from the "baby Gauss" formula $(n(n+1))/2=\sum_{I=1}^n i$ which you then divide by 20 since each side is assumed as being equally likely.

Comment: Do you get to reroll if the roll is not *exactly* $20$, or if it's not *at least* $20$?  Also, are you counting the $+11$ adjustment?  It looks like you are, but I just want to make sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, to calculate the chance of getting at least a 20 on a single 1d20+11 roll, you count the number of "successful" possibilities and divide it by the total possibilities. Since you have the +11 bonus, it would suffice to roll an 9. In which case, there are 12 distinct "successful" cases (namely rolling a natural 10, 11, ..., 20) and 20 total cases. So the probability of rolling at least a 20 on a single 1d20+9 roll would simply be $\frac{12}{20} = \frac{3}{5}$.

Now, since you can re-roll a 1d20+11 if the first throw was unsuccessful, we split into multiple "scenarios". The probability of failure on the first throw would be $1-\frac{3}{5} = \frac{2}{5}$. The probability of success and failure of the second throw would similarly be $\frac{3}{5}$ and $\frac{2}{5}$, respectively. Since the first and the second throw are independent, we can multiply probabilities together to get the compound probability. So we have 3 basic cases:

$$\begin{cases}
\frac{3}{5},  & \text{if the first throw succeeds} \\
\frac{2}{5}*\frac{3}{5} = \frac{6}{25}, & \text{if the first throw fails, but the second one succeeds}\\
\frac{2}{5}*\frac{2}{5} = \frac{4}{25}, & \text{if both throws fail.}
\end{cases}$$

So, to find the total probability of "success" (i.e. at least one of the throws is successful), simply add up the probabilities of the successful cases.
$$\frac{3}{5}+\frac{6}{25} = \frac{21}{25} = 84\%  \text{ chance of success.}$$